# Number and nature of independent variables to descibe a thermodynamic system

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, degrees-of-freedom

In a thermodynamic system which has n ways of doing work, we have in total n+1 vaiables or degrees of freedom to know about the system. However, how many of the n+1 have to be intensive or extensive and how is this decided? Or is it completely random? Also, we have the Gibbs-Duhem relation under consideration. What role does it play in all this?